# DELETE statement on SQLite (sql.js) does nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I am trying to delete a row on a SQLite database from node.js but when the statement gets executed the row is not deleted.

The SQL statement works just fine if I execute it on DB Browser for SQLite. Loading the database is working fine and the /api/deleteitem endpoint is being executed but it does nothing.

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const sqlite = require('sql.js');

const filebuffer = fs.readFileSync('db/knowledge');

const db = new sqlite.Database(filebuffer);

const app = express();

app.delete('/api/deleteitem', (req,res) => {

  db.run(`delete from knowledge_items where item_id = "107"`);
  res.sendStatus(204);

});
```

Row with item_id = 107 still exists after it gets executed.

Comment: I recommend _not_ using double quotes for string literals, i.e. use `where item_id = '107'`.  It might not matter, but double quotes in SQLite escape qualifiers (columns, tables, etc.).

Comment: I tried it without quotes and still didn't work :(

Comment: From [the source](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/): *It uses a virtual database file stored in memory, and thus doesn't persist the changes made to the database.* Did you follow the steps in the **write a database to the disk** section of the readme?

Comment: Also: *If you are building a native application in JavaScript (using Electron for instance), **or are working in node.js**, you will likely prefer to use a native binding of SQLite to JavaScript.*

Comment: Thanks Shawn. Yeah I am working in node.js. I will have to look for an alternative to this SQLite port. I am not tied to SQLite either so perhaps there is a better alternative for simple insert/delete/update application